# Sum of increasing probability series and average of increasing series

Tags: probability, summation

If I let $b1> b2> . . . > b_n$ be a series of probabilities, where $∑_ib_i= 1$, and let $s1, . . . , s_n$ be a *strictly* increasing sequence of positive numbers.

Is it true that $∑_ib_is_i ≤ (1/n)∑_is_i$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality

It is a particular case of the Chebyshev's sum inequality

Now since
$$ b_1 > b_2 > \ldots > b_n$$
$$ s_1 < s_2 < \ldots < s_n$$

By Chebyshev's sum inequality, we have
$$ \frac {1} {n} \sum_{i=1}^n b_is_i <
\left(\frac {1} {n} \sum_{i=1}^n b_i\right)
\left(\frac {1} {n} \sum_{i=1}^n s_i\right)$$

As
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n b_i = 1 $$

The above inequality simplifies to

$$ \frac {1} {n} \sum_{i=1}^n b_is_i < \frac {1} {n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n s_i 
\iff \sum_{i=1}^n b_is_i < \frac {1} {n} \sum_{i=1}^n s_i  $$